# Subset panel data according to temporal order

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I want to select cases to estimate the effect of aid on conflict. In my case selection, I just want to have cases where Aid is chronological before conflict. 
Here is an example dataset:

```
dt <- data.frame(name= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(3,3,3)), 
                 year=c(2001:2003), Aid=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 conflict=c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

Because in country B aid is after the conflict, I want to exclude this case. 
In the end the dataset should look like this:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(name= rep(c("A", "C"), c(3,3)), 
                       year=c(2001:2003), Aid=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                       conflict=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Like so.

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt                                   %>% 
     group_by(name)                        %>% 
     mutate(
         aid_year = match(1, Aid),
         conflict_year = match(1, conflict)
       )                                   %>% 
     filter(aid_year <= conflict_year)

## # A tibble: 6 x 6
## # Groups:   name [2]
##   name   year   Aid conflict aid_year conflict_year
##   <fct> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>    <int>         <int>
## 1 A      2001    1.       0.        1             3
## 2 A      2002    0.       0.        1             3
## 3 A      2003    0.       1.        1             3
## 4 C      2001    1.       0.        1             2
## 5 C      2002    0.       1.        1             2
## 6 C      2003    1.       1.        1             2
```

This assumes that all years are the same in all countries. If not then you should replace `match(1, Aid)` with something that gets the actual year (something like `conflict_year = year[conflict_year]` within the `mutate`).

Also, IMHO cross-country regressions are a big fat waste of time... but I guess that isn't part of the answer, and doubtless you know what you are doing....

Comment: Thanks for you answer :). I agree, cross-country regressions are a big waste of time. I do CEM with artificial grid cells!

Comment: No prob, feel free to accept if it works. What is CEM?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `any` with `filter`

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(any(Aid == conflict))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   name [2]
#   name   year   Aid conflict
#   <fct> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 A      2001     1        0
#2 A      2002     0        0
#3 A      2003     0        1
#4 C      2001     1        0
#5 C      2002     0        1
#6 C      2003     1        1
```